# symbol lookup error: ./executableName: undefined symbol: _ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC2Ev

Tags: linux, qt, linker, shared-libraries, symbol-table

I am trying to run an executable on Linux Mint 16 x64 that was compiled for Ubuntu 12 x64.
The executable uses Qt 5.1.1 dynamically during runtime. I get the error:

```
loaded the dummy plugin 
loaded the Linux plugin 
updating server status 
./executableName: symbol lookup error: ./executableName: undefined symbol: _ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC2Ev
```

When I run

```
ldd executableName | grep "not found"
```

searching for missing dependencies I get no result; all dynamic dependencies seem to be found, but the undefined symbol error above persists.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A quick help:

```
$ echo _ZN18QXmlDefaultHandlerC2Ev|c++filt
QXmlDefaultHandler::QXmlDefaultHandler()
```

Thus, you don't have a constructor for `QXmlDefaultHandler`. Googling for that we can found here, that at least Qt-4.8 and Qt-5.3 contains this library.

I think, there is some type of incompatibility between your actual running Qt library and between for which the executable was compiled for. My suggestion were to recompile that executable from source, *but* on your mint.

It is not impossible, that porting the source package from ubuntu will be a little bit hard for you, in this case I suggest a simple upstream source recompilation (or even binary download, if there is one).

Comment: @peterh: I have a similar problem which says `tsk_img_open_sing` function of `sleuthkit` library as `undefined symbol`. I have included `libtsk.h` and `echo tsk_img_open_sing|c++filt` gives output as `tsk_img_open_sing`. Why is it so?

Comment: @Jackz `c++filt` is needed only to convert cryptic c++ function names to their c++ form (normal binaries can't have X::~X() and similar function names, this is why it is needed.). But this is a C function, so c++filt isn't needed. `nm --dynamic /path/to/sleuthkit.so` says which function names are exported by this library, your sleuthkit.so must contain that. If not, there is a problem with your sleuthkit. If yet, then probably this sleuthkit library can't be found somehow by your compiler.

Comment: @Jackz Better if you ask this in a new question, and then refer me here into that in a comment. So I could write a clear answer, and you could upvote me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Ubuntu binaries on Mint like that; binaries are generally not binary-compatible between distributions. Can you find a Mint build? If not, you'll have to build it yourself.

Comment: *"binaries are generally not binary-compatible between distributions"*: that is *generally* not true. I regularly run binaries compiled on other distributions - if the right versions of the right libraries are there, executables often work without a problem...

Comment: I agree that something compiled for a Fedora based OS might have trouble executing on say Debian, but considering Mint is a [fork off of Ubuntu](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint), Ubuntu binaries often can be coaxed into executing.

I do agree though that if I had source for my particular problem that building for Mint would be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, but the greatest difference between Mint and Ubuntu that Mint is based on KDE. Probably it has its own Qt distro, which differs a lot from the Ubuntu one (for example, some of its help libs to the Qt are distributed in separate packages).